# Why grep doesn't work in the /usr/lib/systemd/system directory?

Tags: systemd, grep

The other day I was on a RHEL7.1 system and I wanted to search for a specific word in the /usr/lib/systemd/system directory where all the systemd unit files are located.
I used the grep command as usual. See what happened:

```
# cd /usr/lib/systemd/system
# grep After *
grep: invalid option -- '.'
Usage: grep [OPTION]... PATTERN [FILE]...
Try 'grep --help' for more information.
```

Then, I tried on RHEL7.0, RHEL7.2, RHEL7.3 and got the same result.
If I use the grep command in any other directory everything works fine.
Who can tell me why I got this strange behavior?

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that there is a file in that directory that begins with a dash, namely `-.slice`.

When you use `*` all the file names become arguments to the `grep`, and `-.slice` gets interpreted as an attempt to pass an option to grep. Since the first character after the dash is a dot, you get that message:

```
grep: invalid option -- '.'
```

You'll find that you have the same problem with shell expansion in the directory if you just try

```
ls *
```

Once the issue is understood, the [answer is easily found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2427913/how-can-i-grep-for-a-string-that-begins-with-a-dash-hyphen).   That is, you can add a double dash to indicate to `grep` that the list of normal options has ended and all following arguments are to be treated as file names:

```
grep After -- *
```